# Is it possible to patch port forwards in a Skaffold profile

Tags: skaffold

I have a port forward definition in my *skaffold.yaml* and I want to add another port forward if a profile is enabled. For some reason, the port forward definition provided by the profile overrides already existing port forwards instead of adding to them.

Here’s how my definition looks like:

```yaml
...
profiles:
  - name: port6000
    patches:
      - op: add
        path: /portForward
        value:
          - resourceType: service
            resourceName: service6000
            namespace: default
            port: 6000
            localPort: 6001
...
portForward:
  - resourceType: service
    resourceName: service5800
    namespace: default
    port: 5800
    localPort: 5801
```

The problem is that when the `port6000` profile is enabled port 5800 is not forwarded but port 6000 only.

Is there something wrong with this definition? When I change *path* to `/portForward/-` I’m getting `line 24: cannot unmarshal !!seq into latest.PortForwardResource` error. Is it possible to patch port forward definitions in profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from the Skaffold community at [`#skaffold` channel on the Kubernetes Slack](https://kubernetes.slack.com/messages/CABQMSZA6/). Posting it here in case someone will face the same issue as I did.

Here's the correct patch definition for the `portForward` node.

```yaml
...
profiles:
  - name: port6000
    patches:
      - op: add
        path: /portForward/-
        value:
          resourceType: service
          resourceName: service6000
          namespace: default
          port: 6000
          localPort: 6001
...
portForward:
  - resourceType: service
    resourceName: service5800
    namespace: default
    port: 5800
    localPort: 5801
```

Corrections made:

1. Set `path` to `/portForward/-`
2. Remove `-` from the `value`, it should not be a list but a record